# Trying my hand at hooks and state in a function in React.js

Tags: html, reactjs

Is this code syntactically correct? The effect I'm trying to achieve is for the text to appear once the button has been clicked...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Example(){
  const [state, setState] = useState({shows: false});

  return(
    <div>{state.shows && <p>hi</p>}
      <button onClick={() => setState({shows: true})}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Sure, but for simple state it is usually better to name the state object for what it holds, i.e. `shows` and `setShows`, and give the initial value directly, i.e. `useState(false)`. Your render then would be `<div>{shows && <p>...` For more complex state and mutations useReducer is recommended.

Comment: Determining if code is syntactically correct is pretty easy--see if it makes it past the parser. Maybe you meant something different.

Comment: @DrewReese Thats a good way to make it simpler...but Jiml made it apparent that I didn't have to change the conts.

Comment: @user12099646, true, be that as it may, but when you start creating or working with functional components with several state hooks you'll appreciate having meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you don't need using object

```
function Example(){
 const [state, setState] = useState(false);

 return(
  <div>{state && <p>hi</p>}
   <button onClick={() => setState(true)}>
     Click me
   </button>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have implemented is fine.

But, Hooks are used to simplify the use of react state.

Hence, in your case, writing in the below format would considered as perfect

```
const [shows, updateShow] = useState(false);
<button onClick={() => updateShow(!shows)}>Click me</button>
```

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html